# Subtracting dates and get difference in days

Tags: php, html

First, I want to say thanks for taking a look at my question. So what I am trying to do is subtract 2 dates and find the difference in days.

I tried something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <?php
        // initialize a session
        session_start();
    ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">

            <input type="date" name="startdate" value="startdate"> 
            to <input type="date" name="enddate" value="enddate"> 
            <br/><br/>

            <input type="submit" name="Search" value="Search">

        </form>

        <?php 
            if(isset($_POST['Search'])) {
                $difInDays=$_POST['enddate']-$_POST['startdate'];
                //and $difInDays=$_POST['enddate']->diff($_POST['startdate']);
                echo $difInDays;
            }
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Any advice would be great, thanks so much! :D

Comment: Just search for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always advocate using the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/DateTime) and [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/DateInterval) classes for this type of thing.

```
$date1 = new DateTime($_POST['startdate']);
$date2 = new DateTime($_POST['enddate']);

/** @var DateInterval $diff */
$diff = date_diff($date1, $date2);

// You can look at the documentation for DateInterval,
//  but suffice it to say that its member variable "d" refers to the "day" part of the difference
echo $diff->d;
```

(This assumes that the form values are entered in "Y-m-d" format)

Answer (score 1):

For date difference use `Diff` php function like this :

```
   $date1 = new DateTime("2013-11-21 12:59:00");
    $date2 = new DateTime("2013-11-21 13:01:00");
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2); 

  echo "DIFF: ".$interval->format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s");
```

If you are interesting in days get only `d` parameter

Comment: Is there any way to subtract two dates using y-m-d? I would use datetime but the information is gathered from a form.

Comment: sure remove the time. like DateTime("2013-10-20");